# PHP & MYSQL Insert value text splitting ":" into next column e,g, name:email:type

Tags: php

so how would this be done?

so far i have:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
$info = $_POST["email"];
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$query = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `email`(`email`,`ip`) VALUES ('{$info}', '{$ip}')");
?>
<html>
<form action="" method="POST">
<textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="in">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert">
</form>
```

The Values of the text area aka "in" will be something like 127.0.0.1:8080:hello@example.com

How would I use text splitting to split the ":" into the next insert value to do this?

Also: Bare in mind I want the IP:Port in the IP section, thanks!
Thanks!

Comment: why are u using `{}` around `{$info}`..? it should be `$info`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode()` for this
http://www.php.net/explode

```
 $string = '127.0.0.1:8080:hello@example.com';
 $arrray = explode(':',$string);
 echo $array[0]; // prints 127.0.0.1
```

So IP will be  -> `$array[0]`
Port will be -> `$array[1]`
Email adress -> `$array[2]`

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `user`(`user`,`country`, `state`, `city`) VALUES ('{$user}', '{$country}', '{$state}', '{$city}')"); Getting a error on that line with: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null and Notice: Undefined variable: link

Comment: problem is with `$link` see what you get `var_dump($link)`

Comment: $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "user");

Comment: `var_dump` right after `require once('db.php');` and see what yo get

Answer (score 1):

https://eval.in/84451

Use explode():

```
$string = '127.0.0.1:8080:hello@example.com';
$ary = explode(':',$string);
var_dump($ary);
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://eval.in/84458

Try this:

```
$string = '127.0.0.1:8080:hello@example.com';
$arr = explode(':',$string);
$val="";
foreach ($arr as $a){
  $val .= "'$a'"." ,";
}
$val=rtrim($val,",");
$sql = "insert into table(ip,name,email) value(".$val.")";
echo $sql;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
insert into table(ip,name,email) value('127.0.0.1' ,'8080' ,'hello@example.com' )
```